# Selecting Samples in Scikit-Learn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there any way of automatically selecting the 'training samples' from the collection of features for better fit of the model (DT or SVM)? I know about selecting the 'features'. But I am talking about selecting the 'samples' after selecting the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to split your set into training, testing, and cross validation sets.  Check out [`sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html).  But also take a look at the [plethora of advanced splitting methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cross_validation) that are also available in SK-Learn.

Here's an example with `test_train_split`:

```
In:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
a, b = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
a

Out:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

In: 
list(b)


Out:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In:
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(a, b, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
a_train

Out:
array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])

In:
b_train

Out:
[2, 0, 3]

In:
a_test

Out:
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])

In:
b_test

Out:
[1, 4]
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show an example how plethora of advanced splitting methods is used

Comment: The example provided answers the original question of how to split the dataset without moving too far off topic.  As you move into more advanced splitting methods, it becomes a discussion about cross validation methods rather than dataset splitting.  This is a great discussion to have and I suggest you post a question on the topic but it leads future readers too far astray from the original question.  Take a look at the link that I provided as it actually has an example provided for every cross-validation method.  Just click on the method and you will see the example half way down the page :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways to do feature selections: `Univariate Feature Selection` and `L1-based Sparse Feature Selection`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif, SelectKBest
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# simulate some artificial data: 2000 obs, features: 1000-dim
# but only 2 out 1000 features are informative, the rest 998 features are noises
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=2000, n_features=1000, n_informative=2, random_state=0)
X.shape

Out[153]: (2000, 1000)

# Univariate Feature Selection: select 20 best from 1000 features
# ==========================================================================
# classification F-test
X_selected = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=20).fit_transform(X, y)
X_selected.shape
# or to visualize each f-score/p-value of 1000 features
X_f_scores, X_f_pval = f_classif(X, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.plot(X_f_scores)
ax.set_title('Univariate Feature Selection: Classification F-Score')
ax.set_xlabel('features')
ax.set_ylabel('F-score')
# which features are most important: top 10
np.argsort(X_f_scores)[-10:]  # argsort is from smallest to largest

Out[154]: array([940, 163, 574, 969, 994, 977, 360, 291, 838, 524])
```

[image]

```
# L1-based Sparse Feature Selection: any algo implementation penalty 'l1'
# ==========================================================================
# use LinearSVC for example here
# other popular choices: logistic regression, Lasso (for regression)
feature_selector = LinearSVC(C=0.01, penalty='l1', dual=False)
feature_selector.fit(X, y)
# get features with non-zero coefficients: exactly 2
(feature_selector.coef_ != 0.0).sum()

Out[155]: 2

X_selected_l1 = feature_selector.transform(X)
# or X[:, feature_selector.coef_ != 0.0]
```

Comment: I was taking about about selecting samples. You did select 2 features out of 1000 features. Now I want to select few best samples out of 1000 samples for each feature.

Comment: @jean What's the purpose of selecting samples? selecting a (potentially biased) training sample to improve the testing performance?

Comment: yes, since the samples contain outliers, I want to make more better model without taking the outliers during learning

Comment: @jean Not sure whether the approach you just described is valid. It sounds a bit `data snooping` to me. :-) For standard outlier detection, I would recommend `one-class KMeans`. Let's wait some answers from others. :-)